# my android app use lots of memory

Tags: android, memory

I have simple android app. App includes around 50 images, mostly PNG format, but also most of them are icon size. There is about 5 layouts and use Google maps and WebView. App itself weights bit under 6MB.

Then i run all of app options and then i look into app settings -> cached processes, i see my app uses 70 MB of RAM !!!

Im calling `finish()` method wherea i can, but that doesnt help. What could help to reduce memory use ?

Even Angry birds is using less !

Comment: What's the collective size of your images on screen vs. all images. My guess is that it is simply caching your image resources for faster loads.

Comment: Also, PNGs might be compressed.

Comment: i dont know what do you mean size of images on screen. All my images weight 4.40 MB

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you're loading your Bitmaps with [methods that create immutable Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.util.DisplayMetrics,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) and not releasing them adequately (you have to take care to dispose of all of their references or else the garbage collector will never free the space they're using.

If that's the case, [this reference](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) might help you with the Bitmaps you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use 9 patch [PNG images](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for your application. This will definitely help you to reduce cache size as well as application size. More over deploy you application code according to android life cycle, excessive use of finish() make the activity to onpause() state, so use onDestroy() where you want to kill that activity.

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable folder and put all those 9 patch image there.Deploy onDestroy() to fill the activity

Answer (score 1):

Please compress each and every image without affect image quality and then take care of leaked memory. Each activity action completed then finish that activity. once you exit from application. destroy all running methods. if you need to clear memory manually, by calling the .recycle() method of your bitmap object.I think its help you to reduce memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it may help i guess:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.LayoutId));
System.gc();
}
```

Comment: Can we use `unBindDrawables` for any view? Does it have any adverse affects like crashing the app or something?